# How to add dynamically icons to text input with JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I am building this chat app. My idea is to display icons in `writeText.value`. It should be looking like the emojis in Messenger for example. As soon as the icon button is clicked it should add to `writeText.value` not icon's tag  but it's look.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Yoo!</title>
    <script src="app.js" async></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
        <h1></h1>
        <div class="nav-space">
            <img alt="" class="friend-img">
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="chat-section">
    </div>
    <div class="input-section">
        <i class="fas fa-icons emojis"></i>
        <input type="text" class="write-text" placeholder="Write message">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-up send"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="emojis-section">
        <i class="fas fa-tired"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-surprise"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-smile-wink"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-smile-beam"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-sad-tear"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-sad-cry"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-meh-rolling-eyes"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-meh-blank"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-laugh-wink"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-laugh-squint"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-laugh-beam"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-laugh"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-kiss-wink-heart"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-kiss-beam"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-kiss"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-grin-wink"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-grin-tongue-wink"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-grin-tongue-squint"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-grin-tongue"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-grin-tears"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-grin-stars"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-grin-squint-tears"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-grin-hearts"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-grin-alt"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-grin"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-angry"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-smile"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-frown"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-meh"></i>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
//!GLOBAL VARIABLES
const writeText = document.querySelector('.write-text')

//!RUNNING FUNCTIONS
chooseFriend()
sendMessage()

//!FUNCTIONS
function chooseFriend(){
    const profilePicture = document.querySelector('.nav-space img')
    const profileName = document.querySelector('nav h1')
    let profiles = [
    {picture:"../imgs/img1.jpg", name: "Mark Zuckerberg"},
    {picture:"../imgs/img2.jpg", name: "Zoe Vegas"},
    {picture:"../imgs/img3.jpg", name: "Juan Pablo"},
    {picture:"../imgs/img4.jpg", name: "Chi Song"},
    {picture:"../imgs/img5.jpg", name: "Ji Malo Lin"},
    ];
    let random = Math.floor((Math.random() * profiles.length))

    profilePicture.src = profiles[random].picture
    profileName.textContent = profiles[random].name
}

function sendMessage(){
    const chatSection = document.querySelector('.chat-section')
    const sendBtn = document.querySelector('.send')
    let answers = [
        "Not much and you?",
        "Thanks, bro!",
        "Absolutely!",
        "I am fine and you?",
        "Yeah right! XDXDXD"
    ];
    
    sendBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        if(writeText.value == ""){
            return
        } else{
            let today = new Date()
    
            //!you text
            const yourMessage = document.createElement('div')
            let yourTime
    
            if(today.getMinutes() < 10){
                yourTime = today.getHours() + ":0" + today.getMinutes()
            } else{
                yourTime = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes()
            }
            yourMessage.classList.add('your-message')
            yourMessage.innerHTML = `
            <p>${writeText.value}</p>
            <span>${yourTime}</span>
            `;
            chatSection.appendChild(yourMessage)
            writeText.value = ""
    
            //!friend texts
            let randomAnswer = Math.floor((Math.random() * answers.length));
            const theirMessage = document.createElement('div')
            let theirTime
    
            if(today.getMinutes() < 10){
                theirTime = today.getHours() + ":0" + today.getMinutes()
            } else{
                theirTime = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes()
            }
            theirMessage.classList.add('friends-message')
            theirMessage.innerHTML = `
                <p>${answers[randomAnswer]}</p>
                <span>${theirTime}</span>
            `;
            chatSection.appendChild(theirMessage)
        }
    })
}

//!DEVELOPING
const emojisBtn = document.querySelector('.emojis')
const emojisSection = document.querySelector('.emojis-section')
const emojis = emojisSection.querySelectorAll("i")

emojisBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    emojisSection.classList.toggle('emojis-section-toggle')
})

emojis.forEach((emoji)=>{
    emoji.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        writeText.value += emoji.outerHTML
        console.log(emoji.outerHTML)
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you share a code pen/code sand box with including the html and css as well?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bpu6ygn4/